# How to do 2 tests when filtering a RDD in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have 2 parameters:

```
NB_line =10
NB2_line=11
```

I have a `python` function, where I did a test of a number of the lines in my dataframe if is not OK.
The dataframe that take 2 cases of number of lines, is `NB_line=10` or `NB2_line=11`.

in the begin it was like this my dataframe:

```
rddLignesErreur=rddstats.filter(lambda x : len(x) != NB_line)
```

After evolution of a use case, I modified it like this:

```
rddLignesErreur=rddstats.filter(lambda x : len(x) != NB_line or len(x) != NB2_line)
```

Is it true or I or no ? ==> I'm beginning in python.

Thank you

Comment: The `or` is correct. Within a lambda expression, you have to write plain python code. Note also that if NB_line and NB2_line are different, your condition will always be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use `not in`?

```
lambda x: len(x) not in {NB_line, NB2_line}
```